# Cannot Fetch 2Checkout Return Parameters

Tags: asp.net, 2checkout

I am facing a problem in fetching return parameters from 2Checkout using .Net, I am currently working on demo mode, products list are sent successfully to 2checkout and when return to (x_receipt_link_url) nothing happen to notify that purchase has been completed  although I am adding a block to fetch the return parameters, 
I am using something like this but with different values

```
//Check for response from 2Checkout
            if (Request.Params["credit_card_processed"] != null)
            {

                //Initialize returned parameters
                string key = Request.Params["key"];
                string sid = "1303908";
                string secret_word = "tango";
                string merchant_order_id = Request.Params["merchant_order_id"];
                string order_number = Request.Params["order_number"];
                string total = Request.Params["total"];

                //Compute our hash
                string string_to_hash = secret_word + sid + order_number + total;
                string our_hash = getMd5Hash(string_to_hash);

                //Compare hashes and update response string
                if (our_hash != key)
                {
                    response = "ERROR: MD5 hash did not match!";
                } 
                else 
                {
                    response = "Thank you for your Order!";
                }
            }
```

Kindly Advice?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2Checkout will return `credit_card_processed=Y` on all successful sales so your hash check should be firing. On demo sales the 2Checkout MD5 Hash will fail to validate because the returned hash is computed using a "1" for the order number. So in your code, you can match it like so:

```
if (Request.Params["demo"] == "Y")
{
    string order_number = "1";
}
```

Your post indicates that you are having a problem fetching the returned parameters , not a problem validating the hash so I think the issue is outside of the code that you posted. Please contact 2Checkout tech support at techsupport@2co.com for assistance with troubleshooting the passback.

Comment: Your answer was part of the solution and the other part is was that i have to change the settings of the 2Co account to use header return in direct return options. and that solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the parameters from your URL

Get the **key, sid,order_number ,tota**l and the **secret word** from your account settings.
if you cant read properly you can use this web to read get parameters better.

http://www.freeformatter.com/url-parser-query-string-splitter.html

2. Convert to MD5 in uppercase

String result = **YourMethodConvertStringToMD5InUpperCase**(secret word* + sid +  order_number  + total );

[!] *dont forget to convert to UpperCase,dont forget convert total to string.*

3. Compare

Compare key generated by 2checkout with result ,this should be true.

Remember if you have the parameter "demo"="Y" you'd use number_order="1" in your encryption md5 as you can read here .

https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/checkout/passback-validation/